# What does "Thing's the same" mean?

Tags: tenet

Neil driving ambulance:

> Protagonist: You knew it was me coming out of that vault. Why didn't you say?
>
> Neil: That's a lot of explaining when someone's about to put a bullet
> in their own brain.
>
> Protagonist: But afterwards?
>
> Neil: **Thing's the same**, I knew you'd be okay.

What does "Thing's the same" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is phrased a little differently in [the script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/tenet-2020.pdf). I also included the next few lines of dialogue after that, because I think they're relevant to the answer:

> **PROTAGONIST:** You knew it was me coming out of that vault. Why didn’t you say?
>
> **NEIL:** That’s a lot of explaining when someone’s about to put a bullet in their own brain.
>
> **PROTAGONIST:** But afterwards –
>
> **NEIL:** With things the same, I knew you’d be okay. What’s happened happened. If I’d told you and you acted differently... who knows? The policy is to suppress.
>
> **PROTAGONIST:** Whose policy?
>
> *Neil GRINS, offering his hand –*
>
> **NEIL:** Ours, my friend. We’re the people saving the world from what might have been...

Taking into account those subsequent lines, I think Neil was saying that since events were unfolding the same way as before (so far as he was aware), he felt confident that history would repeat itself, and that Protagonist would therefore be okay. But if he'd said something when Protagonist was coming out of the vault, he might've altered history, and in that case, who knows how things would've turned out.

So...

> With things the same, I knew you'd be okay.

... can effectively be read as...

> With events unfolding the same way as before, I knew you'd be okay.